# Is there a function $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ , $f>0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ but $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx < \infty $?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

On another note, is there a function   $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ , $|f| =1$ but $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx = 0 $?

Edit: what if one were to relax the condition for the first question to $\limsup_{x\to \infty}f(x)\,dx = \infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As regards the first question, the answer is NO. Let $R>0$ such that $f(x)\geq 1$ for $x\geq R$. Then
$$\int_0^{\infty}f(x) dx\geq \int_R^{\infty}f(x) dx\geq \int_R^{\infty}1 dx=+\infty.$$

As regards the second question, the answer is YES.
Let $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$ for $n\geq 0$, and, for $x\geq 0$, let
$$
f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \mbox{if  $x\in [2H_n,2H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}]$}, \\
      -1 & \mbox{if $ x\in (2H_n+\frac{1}{n+1},2H_n+\frac{2}{n+1})$}.
    \end{cases}
$$
Then $|f(x)|=1$ and $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)=0$.

P.S.  If we relax the condition for the first question to $\limsup_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \infty$ then the answer is YES. Take for example
$$f(x)=e^{-x}+
    \begin{cases}
      n & \mbox{if  $x\in [n,n+1/n^3)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$}, \\
      0 & \mbox{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}
$$
then $f$ is positive and
$$\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^3}=1+\frac{\pi^2}{12}<+\infty.$$

Comment: what if one were to relax the condition to $lim sup_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty?$

Comment: Then the answer for the first question is YES. Try to find an example.

Comment: I'd say it would have to be a periodic function (aka trig function) multiplied with some rational function.

Comment: If the condition is just $\lim\sup_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, think of the graph of a Gaussian distribution (just for the purpose of satisfying the $f > 0$ condition), except at the $k^{\text{th}}$ even integer, insert a rectangle with area $\frac{1}{2^k}$ and height $2^k$.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun you mean like a sharp spike at every even integer? Kind of like a dirac delta function?

Comment: As regards your further question see my edited answer.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some kind of minus sign in the exponent of $e^{}$?

Comment: @ghthorpe Yeah, you could do it that way. The idea is, you want to make some sort of "sharp" thing that gets thinner and thinner (thin enough to allow for the sum of the areas of all the "sharp" things to converge). The reason I mentioned rectangles is because continuity was not mentioned :P

Comment: @RobertZ the key characteristic about your alternating step function is that the intervals are getting smaller right? it wouldn't work for intervals of constant length, right?

Comment: @ghthorpe Exactly!

Answer (score 2):

No for the first question, yes for the second. For the first question, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, and so there exists some $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\geq c$ we have $f(x) > 1$. Therefore,
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx =K+ \int_c^\infty f(x) \,dx > \int_c^\infty dx = \infty$$
for some appropriate real number $K$.

For the second question, let $\mathrm{sgn}: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathrm{sgn}(x\geq0) = 1, \mathrm{sgn}(x< 0) = -1$. Then let $f(x) = \mathrm{sgn}(\sin(e^x))$. Clearly, $\vert f(x)\vert=1$ for all $x$. Further,
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = \int_0^{\ln(\pi)}f(x)\, dx+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\ln(\pi n)}^{\ln(\pi(n+1))} f(x)\, dx$$
$$= \ln(\pi)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (\ln((n+1)\pi) - \ln(n\pi)) \in \mathbb{R}$$
You can then modify $f$ so that the integral is $0$.

EDIT- To do this, suppose the integral comes out to $c>0$. Then let $g(x) = -1$ for $0\leq x < c$, and let $g(x) = f(x-c)$ for $x\geq c$. Then $\int_0^\infty g(x)\, dx = 0$. A similar process works if $c<0$.

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: Then, how you modify $f$ to obtain $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)=0$?

Comment: In theory, find the value of the integral, and change pieces of the intervals on which $f=1$ to $f=-1$ until the integral is $0$ (or the opposite, if the integral were negative).

Comment: Alternatively, suppose the integral comes out to $c>0$. Then let $g(x) = -1$ for $0\leq x < c$, and let $g(x) = f(x-c)$ for $x\geq c$. Then $\int_0^\infty g(x)\, dx = 0$.

Comment: Now it is clear. Why don't you edit your answer with the last comment?

Comment: Good idea, just did that.